# German word for "queue ticket"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, word-choice

When you go to an office you get a ticket with a number. You have to wait until your number is on a display. I want to know the German word for this ticket.

Comment: Well, just "Nummer". "Man zieht eine Nummer."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might not perfectly fit what you want but I can think of

> Wartenummer (or just Nummer)

as a commonly used version. It means <s>queue</s> waiting number and I think it comes from the number on the ticket which is assigned to you.

**Update**

A word for the actual ticket is

> Wartemarke

as used on the [website of a company](http://www.aras-aufrufanlagen.de/wartemarkenspender.html) producing such queuing solutions

As @tofro and @KilianFoth mentioned in the comments this word is mostly used by companies and official/government agencies.

Comment: Apparently they had to invent that word - I don't think "Wartemarke" is commonly used. But they can't really state on their web site they're selling "Nummern"....

Comment: Yes it indeed sounds very strange, I haven't heard that word before either. Maybe best is to go with *Wartenummer*

Comment: "Wartemarke" is the correct term only in the sense that "Postwertzeichen" ist the correct term for "stamp". Government agencies use it, but every normal person just says "Briefmarke". Likewise, every normal person would just use "Nummer".

Comment: @KilianFoth Your comment really made me check on the "Deutsche Post" web site wether they stll use "Postwertzeichen" - And: They still do: *Die sympathischste Form der Freimachung: Briefmarken. Briefmarken / Postwertzeichen kaufen*. And I like "Freimachung" even more than "Postwertzeichen" now...

Comment: @KilianFoth not really: the "Nummer" is written on the Wartemarke, but its not the same. You get a Wartemarke with a (Warte)nummer on it. You often simplify it by saying "Ich ziehe mal eine Nummer" instead of "Ich hole mir mal eine Wartemarke mit einer Nummer darauf". But the phsysical representation of your number/ Nummer is the Wartemarke.

Answer (score 2):

As stated above the requested word is:

> Wartemarke

But the usage in common spoken language is:

> Marke

Even the word:

> Nummer

Is often used as it refers to the number often printed on those queue tickets.

So depending on the context all can be used.

Examples:

> „Ich zieh mir mal ne Nummer“, sagte ich zu meinem Begleiter als wir das Bürgerbüro betraten.
> „Hach schon wieder ’ne Marke holen“, beschwerte sich mein Freund bei mir.
>
> „Wartemarken sind nach dem Aufruf beim Bearbeiter abzugeben“, stand auf einem Schild neben dem Automaten.

Comment: @Jan wie hast du das eingegeben, dass das beginnende  Anführungszeichen, korrekt unten ist?

Comment: Auf Windows: Öffnendes deutsches Anführungszeichen: Alt-0132, schließendes: Alt-0147. Auf Englisch: Alt-0147/Alt-0148. Englische einfache AZ: Alt-0145/Alt-0146. Auf Linux: Oft etwas wie Alt Gr+b (öffnend, deutsch), Alt Gr+n (schließend, deutsch/öffnend, englisch), Alt Gr+m (schließend, englisch) beziehungsweise die letzten Beiden mit Umschalttaste für einfache. Der Apostroph ist auch Alt-0146 (Windows) oder Alt Gr+Umschalt+n (meist Linux).

Comment: Natürlich, ASCII Eingabe, wie konnte ich die nur vergessen.